# How to synchronous render Android View to OpenGL SurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, render

Recently, I want to render Android's native view toOpenGL SurfaceView, the original idea was to capture the view as a bitmap, and then render Bitmap into OpenGL; but obviously this method is not feasible, in the face of some high-speed dynamic updates of the view, only continuous screenshots of the view can render the original view Effect.it's not productive.

Comment: I solved this problem;blog here:[https://blog.csdn.net/u010949962/article/details/41865777/](https://blog.csdn.net/u010949962/article/details/41865777/)

Comment: Source Code here:[https://github.com/Android1404/RenderViewToOpenGL](https://github.com/Android1404/RenderViewToOpenGL)

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is?